# Sum distinct records in a table with duplicates in Teradata

Tags: sql, sum, case, distinct, teradata

I have a table that has some duplicates. I can count the distinct records to get the Total Volume. When I try to Sum when the `CompTia` Code is `B92` and run distinct is still counts the dupes.

**Here is the query:**

```
select 
a.repair_week_period,
count(distinct a.notif_id) as Total_Volume,
sum(distinct case when a.header_comptia_cd = 'B92' then 1 else 0 end) as B92_Sum 
FROM artemis_biz_app.aca_service_event a
where a.Sales_Org_Cd = '8210'
and a.notif_creation_dt >= current_date - 180
group by 1
order by 1
;
```

Is There a way to only SUM the distinct records for B92?

I also tried inner joining the table on itself by selecting the distinct notification id and joining on that notification id, but still getting wrong sum counts.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and expected result will help us in better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Your `B92_Sum` currently returns either `NULL`, `1` or `2`, this is definitely no sum.

To sum distinct values you need something like

```
sum(distinct case when a.header_comptia_cd = 'B92' then column_to_sum else 0 end)
```

If this `column_to_sum` is actually the `notif_id` you get a conditional count but not a sum.

Otherwise the distinct might remove too many vales and then you probably need a Derived Table where you remove duplicates before aggregation:

```
select 
   repair_week_period,
     --no more distinct needed
   count(a.notif_id) as Total_Volume,
   sum(case when a.header_comptia_cd = 'B92' then column_to_sum else 0 end) as B92_Sum 
FROM 
 (
   select repair_week_period,
      notif_id
      header_comptia_cd,
      column_to_sum
   from artemis_biz_app.aca_service_event
   where a.Sales_Org_Cd = '8210'
   and a.notif_creation_dt >= current_date - 180
     -- only onw row per notif_id
   qualify row_number() over (partition by notif_id order by ???) = 1
 ) a
group by 1
order by 1
;
```

Comment: In the table the notif_id can either be 1 or more than 1 as a record can have more than one notif_id. When I try to run  sum(distinct case when a.header_comptia_cd = 'B92' then column_to_sum else 0 end) . I get that an error that column_to_sum is not found.

Comment: @txwylde: Of course there's no `column_to_sum`, this is *your* column you try to sum. Without some example data and the expected result (including the logic behind) there's no way to help you any further.

Comment: Having issues pasting in example data, tells me its too long. The notif_id looks like this:  030249365316 the header_comptia_cd looks like this: B81. The record can have either distinct notif_id and header_comptia_cd or multiple notif_id and header_comptia_cd.

Comment: repair_week_period  notif_id                  header_comptia_cd
------------------  ------------------------  -----------------
FY2016P11W4         030249365316              B33              
FY2016P11W4         030249364022              B81

Answer (score 0):

@dnoeth It seems the solution to my problem was not to `SUM` the data, but to `count` `distinct` it.

This is how I resolved my problem:

```
count(distinct case when a.header_comptia_cd = 'B92' then a.notif_id else NULL end) as B92_Sum
```